# JBoss as7 to WildFly migration with Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jboss, jboss7.x, wildfly

I try to migrate from JBoss AS 7 to Wildfly 8.2. and i have really problems with hibernate.

I'm using maven with the dependenies:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
  <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
  <version>4.2.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

and

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
  <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

When i start my application witch is working in AS 7 i get the error in wildfly:

```
10:08:11,485 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 53) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.persistenceunit."com.haslerrail.MyDatabase.web.war#MyDatabase": org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.persistenceunit."com.haslerrail.MyDatabase.web.war#MyDatabase": javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: MyDatabase] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
      at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:172) [wildfly-jpa-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
      at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:117) [wildfly-jpa-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
      at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_65]
      at org.wildfly.security.manager.WildFlySecurityManager.doChecked(WildFlySecurityManager.java:474)
      at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:182) [wildfly-jpa-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_65]
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_65]
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_65]
      at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122)
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: MyDatabase] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
      at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.persistenceException(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1239) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
      at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.access$600(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:120) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
      at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:855) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
      at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:845) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
      at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.withTccl(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:398) [hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
      at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:844) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
      at org.jboss.as.jpa.hibernate4.TwoPhaseBootstrapImpl.build(TwoPhaseBootstrapImpl.java:44) [jipijapa-hibernate4-3-1.0.1.Final.jar:]
      at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:154) [wildfly-jpa-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
      ... 8 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Attribute [com.haslerrail.MyDatabase.server.db.entity.Widget.type] was annotated as enumerated, but its java type is not an enum [java.lang.String]
      at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.SimpleValueBinder.setType(SimpleValueBinder.java:257) [hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
      at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.PropertyBinder.makePropertyAndValue(PropertyBinder.java:195) [hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
      at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.PropertyBinder.makePropertyValueAndBind(PropertyBinder.java:216) [hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
      at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.processElementAnnotations(AnnotationBinder.java:2241) [hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
      at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.processIdPropertiesIfNotAlready(AnnotationBinder.java:963) [hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
      at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.bindClass(AnnotationBinder.java:796) [hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
      at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration$MetadataSourceQueue.processAnnotatedClassesQueue(Configuration.java:3845) [hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
      at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration$MetadataSourceQueue.processMetadata(Configuration.java:3799) [hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
      at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1412) [hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
      at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1846) [hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
      at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:852) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
      ... 13 more
```

I tried to find any documentation for hibernate and wildfly but the documentaion on https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/Hibernate is empty!!!!

Does anyone have experience with migration from AS 7 to Wildfly and hibernate? What do I need to adjust?

Comment: Well you're already deploying an API dependency with your application. You should mark your hibernate dependencies as provided, JBoss provides them. Don't ever deploy APIs such as JPA with your application, they are for compilation purposes only.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I changed the dependency to provided but the error is still the same...!

Comment: @Gimby .. That is not true. What if we want to use a library version other than what is provided in Jboss?

Comment: @Rohit Then you deploy another -implementation- (such as EclipseLink, or even a newer version of Hibernate), but you still never deploy the -api- (JPA). Most people don't seem to understand the difference.

Comment: @Gimpy... To deploy the newer(or desired) version, marking it as provided will not help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The container version of the Hibernate is given precedence over your application packaged version in Java EE conatiners. And hence the error.

To avoid this situation you need to control classloading explicitly and exclude the container library. read [here](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/Class+Loading+in+WildFly)

Basically you will need to provide a `jboss-deployment-structure.xml` for fine grain control over dependencies.

for eg:

```
    <jboss-deployment-structure>
        <deployment>
            <exclusions>
                <!-- Exclude container version of hibernate. By default its version 4, we want 
                    bundled version to load -->
                <module name="org.hibernate" slot="main" />
            </exclusions>
        </deployment>
    </jboss-deployment-structure>
```

Comment: Ok, do you have a running example of a jboss-deployment-structure.xml file? After adding your lines in my jboss-deployment-structure.xml file i get no error message anymore but some Errors like ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS014613: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "xxxx.war")]) What does this mean?

Comment: I am afraid there is not one jboss-deployment-structure.xml structure that suits all situations. You may need to see individual error messages to identify which libraries are causing problems.

Comment: I just can't believe, that i'm the first one who is using wildfly with hibernate. But there is absolute no useful documentation or any example to find. It is very frustrating...

Comment: The line you have shared tells that the depoyment has failed, there should  be stacktrace somewhere in the logs that tells what has failed exactly. I would assume it would be related to some other library now as hibernate is taken care of. I would suggest if its related to some other library mark this as answer and open a separate question  as this question may help other users in future.

Comment: Ok, now i removed all the files in my project, that gave errors. And now i still have the "Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory" error. So i don't believe the error is in the jboss-deployment-structure.xml file...

Comment: Again, what is the root cause?

Comment: 08:10:59,510 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 53) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.persistenceunit."XXX.war#Xxx": org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.persistenceunit."XXX.web.war#Xxx": javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: Xxx] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
 at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:172) [wildfly-jpa-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]

Comment: Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: Aura] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
 at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.persistenceException(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1239)
 at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.access$600(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:120)
 at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:855)

Answer (score 2):

After hours of trying, this version of jboss-deployment-structure.xml file seems to work for me:

```
<jboss-deployment-structure>
  <deployment>
    <exclusions>
      <module name="org.hibernate" slot="main" />
    </exclusions>
    <dependencies>
      <module name="org.hibernate" />
    </dependencies>
  </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

I think i need also "org.hibernate" as dependencies because i'm using Flyway for database migration... Otherwise i get some error message.

Without Flyway, the answer from Rohit seems to be correct... (But i haven't tested it!)

Comment: I know this is an old thread, but just curious, does your solution use hibernate 4.2.0 Final instead of 4.3.7 Final provided by wildfly 8.2? How did you make sure that it uses your hibenate (in this case 4.2.0 final)